Enforcing comparison contraints in Enum genereic parameters
I attempted using comparison constraints on Enum generic parameters as follows:
public abstract class StateMachine {...}

public abstract class StateMachine<TState, TCommand>:
    StateMachine
    where TState: struct, Enum
    where TCommand: struct, Enum
{
    public TState StateInitial { get; private set; }

    protected StateMachine(TState stateInitial) => this.StateInitial = stateInitial;
}

public abstract class FiniteStateMachine<TState, TCommand>:
    StateMachine<TState, TCommand>
    where TState: struct, Enum
    where TCommand: struct, Enum
{
    protected FiniteStateMachine(TState stateInitial)
        : base(stateInitial)
    {
        // Compiler Error CS0019:
        // Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'TState' and 'TState'.
        // Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'TCommand' and 'TCommand'.
        var stateEquals = (default(TState) == default(TState));
        var commandEquals = (default(TCommand) == default(TCommand));
    }
}

public sealed class RouterFiniteStateMachine:
    FiniteStateMachine<RouterFiniteStateMachine.EnumState, RouterFiniteStateMachine.EnumCommand>
{
    public enum EnumState { Unplugged, PluggedIn, }
    public enum EnumCommand { None, PlugIn, UnPlug, }

    public RouterFiniteStateMachine()
        : base(EnumState.Unplugged)
    {
        var stateEquals = (default(EnumState) == default(EnumState));
        var commandEquals = (default(EnumCommand) == default(EnumCommand));
    }
}

The comparison in the FiniteStateMachine constructor does not compile with:
Error CS0019: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'TState' and 'TState'

I kind of understand the 'why', and would like to know how I could circumvent this in an elegant way. The base classes perform lots of actions that require == comparisons. If I try to use the IEquatable<T>, IComparable<T> constraints on generics, then RouterFiniteStateMachine will not compile.
Since these state machines are long-lived objects, any amount of statically preloaded operations/overheads are welcome as long as they allow the consuming code to be easier to write and more readable.
I thought of caching the enum values as Int64s but that will not handle UInt64 and vice cersa.
I noticed that by this time (.NET 9 C# 13), the built-in integral numeric types now implement a plethora of useful interfaces e.g.:
public readonly struct Int64:
    IComparable, IConvertible, ISpanFormattable, IFormattable, IComparable<long>, IEquatable<long>, IBinaryInteger<long>, IBinaryNumber<long>, IBitwiseOperators<long, long, long>, INumber<long>, IComparisonOperators<long, long, bool>, IEqualityOperators<long, long, bool>, IModulusOperators<long, long, long>, INumberBase<long>, IAdditionOperators<long, long, long>, IAdditiveIdentity<long, long>, IDecrementOperators<long>, IDivisionOperators<long, long, long>, IIncrementOperators<long>, IMultiplicativeIdentity<long, long>, IMultiplyOperators<long, long, long>, ISpanParsable<long>, IParsable<long>, ISubtractionOperators<long, long, long>, IUnaryPlusOperators<long, long>, IUnaryNegationOperators<long, long>, IShiftOperators<long, int, long>, IMinMaxValue<long>, ISignedNumber<long>

Short of the == operator, what are my best options for making type-safe and performant compositions on the TState TCommand generic parameters? Is this even possible without boxing?

Why would casting to Int64 "not handle" UInt64? As far as equality is concerned, they are the same 64 bits. It doesn't matter whether the type is actually signed or not if you are just comparing equality.

@Sweeper: The question isn't about binary comparison between 8, 16, 32, 64 bit values. It is about the comparison of enum members without boxing. And think about the usage context of the question, which is a state machine controlled by enum member names. My comment about the underlying types was simply exploring neat options for comparison that avoided boxing/allocations. I do agree with you on signed and unsigned types sharing the same bits.

You can use the EqualityComparer trick:
var stateEquals = EqualityComparer<TState>.Default
    .Equals(stateInitial, default(TState));
var commandEquals = EqualityComparer<TCommand>.Default
    .Equals(default(TCommand), default(TCommand));

Which does not result in allocattions on every comparison and provides typesafety.
See also:

Consider having enums auto-implement IEquatable<T>
Proposal: Enums should implement generic IEquatable/IComparable interfaces
[API Proposal]: Enum should implement IBitwiseOperators, IEqualityOperators - enums implementing IEqualityOperators will allow using == in the generic methods.


I haven't seen that approach before. It seems to be quite performant, thanks. The documentation says: The Default property checks whether type T implements the System.IEquatable<T> interface and, if so, returns an EqualityComparer<T> that uses that implementation.. Trying to get to the framework code that does that out of curiosity. Also, thank you for the external links (interesting reads).

However, it does beg the question as to why I cannot provide my own EqualityComparer for enums in general. Or maybe I am circling back to the same question everyone has been asking about the == operators?

@RaheelKhan "Trying to get to the framework code that does that out of curiosity" - internally it uses special comparer - EqualityComparer which uses some runtime magic via RuntimeHelpers.EnumEquals to prevent boxing.

@RaheelKhan "why I cannot provide my own EqualityComparer for enums" - you can but it will suffer from all the problems you have in the FiniteStateMachine's ctor.

RuntimeHelpers were very interesting to inspect. Thank you for addressing the question in its entirety, and then some!
